# Avoiding a race condition

Tags: erlang

The following code snippet is taken page 112 of the book by Francesco Cesarini and Simon Thompson, Erlang Programming, as an illustration of a possible race condition in Erlang.

```
start() -> 
  case whereis(db_server) of
    undefined -> 
      Pid = spawn(db_server, init, []), 
      register(db_server, Pid), 
      {ok, Pid};
    Pid when is_pid(Pid) ->
      {error, already_started}
  end.
```

Without copying the details verbatim, the authors explain that if two processes simultaneously execute start(), then process 1 running the "undefined" section might not complete, because process 2 causes it to be preempted. Process 2 would then run the "undefined" section to completion. Now, when process 1 resumes, db_server has already been registered by process 2, causing the its call to register() to throw a runtime error. I hope you can understand what I mean, because I don't want to filch the book's text.

My question is how can the above **exact** functionality be coded to avoid the potential race condition when two processes simultaneously execute start()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How many servers do you want to start? Your original question implies one, while a comment to @cthulahoops says two, a server and a backup. For two servers you could try something like:

```
start() ->
    case whereis(db_server) of
        undefined ->
            Spid = spawn(db_server, init, []),
            %% In race condition there can be only one that succeeds to register
            case catch register(db_server, Spid) of
                true -> {ok,Spid};             %We are it
                {error,_} ->                   %Server registered, register as backup
                    register(db_server_backup, Spid),
                    {ok,Spid}
            end;
        _ ->                                   %Server registered, start backup
            Bpid = spawn(db_server, init, []),
            register(db_server_backup, Bpid),
            {ok,Bpid}
    end.
```

I haven't run it though.

Comment: I want to start two servers. I originally used the example from the O'Reilly book, because I thought it would be easier for people to understand and, hence, answer my question. I want to start exactly 2 servers (a primary and a backup) to provide failover. I do have code similar to what you suggest, but maybe yours is better at avoiding race conditions.

Answer (score 9):

Generally this is solved by having the spawned process register its own name, and then send back a response to its parent telling the parent whether or not it succeeded.

```
start() ->
   Pid = spawn(db_server, init, [self()]),
   receive {Pid, StartResult} ->
       StartResult
   end.

init(Parent) ->
    try register(db_server, self()) of
        true ->
            Parent ! {ok, started},
            real_init()
    catch error:_ ->
        Parent ! {error, already_started}
    end.
```

(May not compile or work. Typed in here without checking.  :))

You can find a carefully implemented version of this in gen.erl.   In practice, in real code you just use the OTP behaviours to reuse that version.

Comment: The problem for me is that I want to use start/0 as in the question, and not start/1 as you suggest. For example, I want to call start/0 twice, once to spawn db_server and once to spawn db_backup_server, if db_server is already registered.  Thank you for responding.

Comment: I just made the code slightly more generic than yours.   Edited to have just a start/0.

Comment: I've just spotted that you actually want to start two servers rather than failing.  You could edit the catch block to register db_backup_server instead, remembering to handle the error if it is called three times.   This seems like an awkward design choice to me though, I'd rather explicitly start the two

Comment: Me too! Unfortunately, I am constrained by the API, which only allows me to offer a start/0 for both the main server and the backup server. Your re-worked suggestion does look good to me though. Of course, short of formal proof, I can't verify that a race condition could not happen. Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You might use a [gen_server](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/gen_server.html) to serialize the requests.

Comment: I know OTP offers robust solutions to these types of issues, but I am interested in non-OTP "design patterns". Thanks for the response.